# Show different URL in address bar

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have a custom post with post-type "podcast" and now my podcast post single URL is `http://localhost/sitename/blog/podcast/post-name`. But I want to show post-type "podcast" URL like: `http://localhost/sitename/test/podcast/post-name`.

Currently site permalink is set to custom structure with `/blog/%postname%`. So blog is showing with each custom post type. And I want to keep permalink structure same but blog will not show in "podcast" post URL.

I have already created a new file for single podcast with copied `single.php` and changed name to `single-podcast.php`. It's working fine with `http://localhost/xyz/blog/podcast/post-name` but I want to show different name in URL.

Can you please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried rewrite options?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters

Example:

```
[
    'rewrite'   => [
        'slug'         => 'your/custom/post/slug/here',
        'with_front'   => false,
    ],
]
```

Comment: Yes I have added following and the url is creating what I want but I am getting page not found.

$args = array(
  "label" => __( "Podcasts", "" ),
  "public" => false,
  "publicly_queryable" => true,
  "show_ui" => true,
  "show_in_rest" => false,
  "has_archive" => false,
  "show_in_menu" => true,
  "capability_type" => "post",
  "hierarchical" => false,
  "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "/abc/podcast", "with_front" => false ),
  "query_var" => true,
  "taxonomies" => array( "category" ),
);

Comment: Try saving permalinks after setting custom post type slug (Settings -> permalinks -> just save again) and try again. It should work :)

Comment: Note that this code uses the modern array shorthand (using just `[]` for array definition) but old php - versions under 5.3 - will error on it. If it errors for you swap the square brackets with the full version of `array()`.